# Correlating scripts on the same element issue in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have two scripts that hit the same element.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".product-type-simple").each(function(i) 
    {
        $(this).delay((i++) * 100).css({
            marginLeft: '-=150px',
            marginTop: '-=150px',
            opacity: '0',
        });
    });

    $(".product-type-simple").each(function(i) 
    {
        $(this).delay((i++) * 100).animate({
            marginLeft: '+=150px',
            marginTop: '+=150px',
            opacity: '1'
        }, 300);
    });
});
```

This one animates all the products on load (each one separetely with small delay)

```
(function($) {
    $(window).load(function() {
        $('.woocommerce ul.products li.product').on('mouseenter',function(){
            $(this).siblings().animate({
                'opacity' : 0.5,
            },500);
        }).on('mouseleave', function(){
            $(this).siblings().animate({
                'opacity' : 1,
            },500)
        })
    })
 })(jQuery);
```

This one works on hover of the same. It's like a highlight script.

The thing that happens is that If you target the image during their "flying in" from the first script the .stop() from the 2nd script will stop them and it becomes a mess.

I had an impression that $(window).load will take care of that. What other way can I delay sort of the script. Like say wait 10 second after page load then start working.

Comment: I don't think its nice to user to wait 10 seconds until animation stops to be able to interact with your page.

Comment: Well it can be even 5 (about how much time it takes for all products to load).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two flags of each count

var falg1 = 0;

Each loop flag1++;

On mouse enter or mouse leave return if flag1 < $(".selector").length(), jquery rule what you used to loop.

Same for loop2

**Update**

```
var flag1 = 0;
var flag2 = 0;

    $(".product-type-simple").each(function(i) 
        {
         flag1++;
         ...
    });
    $(".product-type-simple").each(function(i) 
        {
         flag2++;
        ...
    });
$('.woocommerce ul.products li.product').on('mouseenter',function(){
               if (flag1 < $(".product-type-simple").length || flag2 < $(".product-type-simple").length) return;            
                // do stuff...
        }).on('mouseleave', function(){
            if (flag1 < $(".product-type-simple").length || flag2 < $(".product-type-simple").length) return;
            // do stuff...
        })
```

This should be it. You exit from mouse event if animations loops are incomplete.

**Update:**

Only one flag required because first loop of delay do not interfere with mouse enter or leave:

Check your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/95kke201/1/

Comment: So, what you're saying to me is that I count the loaded products into a variable and then check if that variable is like >10 then it should start working?

Comment: yes, sorry for double posting and incorrect format but my browser crashed when I submitted.

Comment: Wouldn't the length (number) of the products be equal to the flag1? Because I animate each product. Actually, I think the classes might've confused you. I used different classes for animations and they relate to all the producst that I have. Product-type-simple is same as ul.products li.products. You can use one and the same class in both functions.

Comment: @SilentTremor Forgot to @ you.

Comment: @NikolaL. if you are saing the cont of loop steps is equal with difrent jquery select rules, you are free to use it. The idea is to have the the events attached to your products but no animation to be active at mouse.

Comment: @NikolaL. I did similar something on a website long time ago :) the solution adopted by me was to cover entire section of feature selection and product selection for compare with transparent blanket until animations were ended. Becouse user had te posibility to check unchek filters and animation to run on bacground.

Comment: @NikolaL. actualy you need only one flag :) find in response updated jsfidle.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70201/discussion-between-silenttremor-and-nikola-l).

Answer (score 1):

You can set the mouse events after the last animation completes:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var productTotal = $(".product-type-simple").length - 1;

    $(".product-type-simple").each(function(i) 
    {
        var options = {
            duration: 300
        };

        // Check if this is the last product and set the completion callback
        if (i == productTotal)
        {
            options.complete = setMouseEvents;
        }

        $(this).delay((i++) * 100).css({
            marginLeft: '-=150px',
            marginTop: '-=150px',
            opacity: '0',
        }).animate({
            marginLeft: '+=150px',
            marginTop: '+=150px',
            opacity: '1'
        }, options);
    });
});

var setMouseEvents = function()
{
    $('.woocommerce ul.products li.product').on('mouseenter',function(){
        $(this).siblings().animate({
            'opacity' : 0.5,
        },500);
    }).on('mouseleave', function(){
        $(this).siblings().animate({
            'opacity' : 1,
        },500)
    });
};
```

I made this snippet of top of my head, so I didn't tested it. This is the far safer method to use since you don't need to trust timeouts neither flags(that can mess your code).

Comment: I tried this. The animation of flying in works but not the hover. I'm watching as well trying to find the stumbling stone.

Comment: @NikolaL. sorry but I didn't undertand what you mean. Want you try to make a jsfiddle to help us?

Comment: Trying to find why the hover in your code doesn't work. That's what I said. I'll make a jsfiddle tomorrow.

Comment: Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/95kke201/ . The main problem is the stop() function in the script #2. (which I forgot to add in the initial thread). But it has to have it because otherwise the highlight animation is sloppy and if spammed it'll go crazy.

Comment: @NikolaL. Well I don't know why you didn't tried my solution, but it works and with a clean code using a callback and just **one** `each`, without control variables and that crap. Check out here: http://jsfiddle.net/95kke201/3/ . Anyway, good luck.

Comment: Yeah in JSFiddle seems to work just fine. Could we have a chat to explain me how this work? I don't understand this options.complete. This could very well be the solution as well, but I already made my choice sooner.

Comment: @NikolaL. in short, the [`complete`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) callback is called when the animation ends. So I set the this callback on the last animation only, to make sure it would be called on the end of all animations. That is why I've said its safer. No need of timers or flags. So, at the end of the very last animation, you set the mouse events and they won't mess your animation again.

Answer (score 0):

you can either set a timer on window load event, something like:

```
(function($) {
    $(window).load(function() {
        widnow.setTimeout(function(){
            $('.woocommerce ul.products li.product').on('mouseenter',function(){
                $(this).siblings().animate({
                    'opacity' : 0.5,
                },500);
            }).on('mouseleave', function(){
                $(this).siblings().animate({
                    'opacity' : 1,
                },500)
            });
        }, 10000);
    })
})(jQuery);
```

or you could trigger an event once the first set of animations is done, lets say - 'firstAnimationsSetFinished', and bind the second mouseEnter and mouseLeave events once to this event instead to widget load.

creating a custom event - http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work. The hovering effect for opacity never comes "online".